# How to put result of a request in json file with JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

My code connect to my database and get data of the two last month. I would like now to save the result of the request in a json file, and I don't really how I can do that.

```
async connect() {
        try {
            console.log("Connecting database.....");
            let pool = await sql.connect(this.sqlConfig);
            let result = await pool.request().query('SELECT * FROM PROFACE.dbo.SuiviProduction WHERE MONTH(Time_Stamp) BETWEEN 08 AND 09');
            if (pool)
                console.log("Database connected");
            console.log(result);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

The result of my request look like this :

```
{
  recordsets: [
    [
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      ... 34449 more items
    ]
  ],
  recordset: [
    {
      Time_Stamp: 2019-08-02T20:58:00.000Z,
      Time_Stamp_ms: 64,
      CompteurTotalLot: 0,
      CompteurBonnesLot: 0,
      CompteurRebutsLot: 0,
      CompteurTotalisateur: 2367922
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what part exactly you're having trouble with? There doesn't seem to be any attempt to save the file in your code, so it's not clear on where you're going wrong.

Comment: I don't attempt to save data in file for the moment, I don't know how to do so. I xant to put content of ```result``` in a json file after ```let result = await pool.request().query('SELECT * FROM PROFACE.dbo.SuiviProduction WHERE MONTH(Time_Stamp) BETWEEN 08 AND 09');```

Answer (score 1):

Convert result to json, I don't actually know what `result` is or looks like so this is a guess.

```js
var json = JSON.parse(result);

download(json, 'oof.txt', 'text/plain');
```

Then the function to download:

```js
function download(data, filename, type) {
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: type});
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) // IE10+
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
    else { // Others
        var a = document.createElement("a"),
                url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.body.removeChild(a);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
        }, 0); 
    }
}
```

---

*UPDATE*

You added your result data, this data is already json so you can skip `var json = JSON.parse(result);`

codepen: https://codepen.io/illfre/pen/BaaEwBa

Comment: Does it works with a .json extension instead of .txt ?

Comment: Should do, just change the file type to `application/json` instead of `text/plain`.

Comment: I've added a copepen.

Comment: When I try, there is a SyntaxError : ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1```

Comment: I have added the begginning of result in question.

Comment: It seems like your data is already json, no need to format it. Just throw the result straight into the download function: `download(result, 'oof.json', 'application/json');` I've updated my code pen to show.

Comment: What is suppose to be ```Blob()``` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob This is Blob

Answer (score 0):

variable result is a javascript object and node is printing deep/nested object values as [Object], [Object] with console.log

Please try following code to stringify whole object first and then print on console.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

You can write asynchronously it to a file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('result.txt', JSON.stringify(result), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```

Or synchronously:

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('result.txt', JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: I already print result in console, I want to have result in a independant file